# Weird AngularJS behavior when using dotted

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This code works and displays the image

```
<div class="container" bg-image="{{UrlResource}}">
```

However, when I change it to the code below, it won't display the image anymore but I do see the url in the DOM

```
<div class="container" bg-image="{{model.UrlResource}}">
```

I see the difference in the DOM outputs from the 2 code above

output of 1st code

```
<div class="container" bg-image="http://localhost:9000/ulkOcf855VSmjhCIX9fMeGht8kwUylaD.png" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:9000/ulkOcf855VSmjhCIX9fMeGht8kwUylaD.png); background-size: cover;"></div>
```

output of 2nd code

```
<div class="container" bg-image="http://localhost:9000/ulkOcf855VSmjhCIX9fMeGht8kwUylaD.png"></div>
```

bg-image is a directive

```
 app.directive('bgImage', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch('UrlResource', function(n) {
          if (n) {
            element.css({
              'background-image': 'url(' + attrs.bgImage + ')',
              'background-size': 'cover'
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: I think I now know why :D my $scope.$watch is only watching UrlResource and not model.UrlResource :D

Comment: I should change the directive name because I thought it was one of HTML predefined attributes. LOL! :D

Comment: haha, happens to us all, glad you got it figured out though :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive, Just swap

```
$scope.$watch('UrlResource', function(n) {
```

to

```
$scope.$watch('model.UrlResource', function(n) {
```

in accordance with your new structure.